# Preview won't load on Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

As I have macOS Catalina 10.15.7 late 2012, Xcode 12,.4 is the version I could get.
I am on a course learning iOS and the Preview part of the programme won't load.
Any help appreciated, thanks

[image]

Restarting, searching through similar queries

Comment: Previews can be temperamental even on Xcode 14. With Xcode 12, they were very buggy. Previews can help, but you can also just run your app to see the views.

Comment: Try to deactivate preview, build and run/stop. Then reactivate the preview (ctrl-alt-enter) Also check you have free space in disk : preview need to create and start a (hidden) simulator before displaying something.

Comment: I have also found that running the app in the simulator will fix a recalcitrant preview at times, though YMMV.

Comment: I do highly recommend upgrading to the latest Xcode if you can.